# Error initializing complex filters What is the issue?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I did executed below ffmpeg command for video reverse:

```
   ffmpeg-y-i/storage/emulated/0/Editor/VideoTrim/VideoTrim_134850.mp4-filter_complex[0:v]reverse[v];[0:a]areverse[a]-map[v]-map[a],[0:v]reverse[v];[0:a]areverse[a]-map[v]-map[a]-presetsuperfast/storage/emulated/0/Editor/VideoEdit/1613031543160.mp4


AVLOG: [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7e1f17efe0] Unable to parse graph description substring: "-map[v]-map[a],[0:v]reverse[v];[0:a]areverse[a]-map[v]-map[a]"
AVLOG: Error initializing complex filters.
AVLOG: Invalid argument
```

Comment: It's a quoting/space issue causing a malformed ffmpeg command.

Comment: Can you edit above FFMPEG command?

Comment: No, sorry. I'm not familiar with Android.